# How to add a property of an option selected in one dropdown menu to another dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to add the list of clubs of a selected option from the first dropdown menu to my second dropdown menu. For example, if a user selects 'England' when they are selecting a country in the first dropdown menu, then the options for the second dropdown menu should be all the elements of englandclubs (the clubs property of the england object) - where each element of that array is an option (i.e. Arsenal F.C., Aston Villa F.C., ..., West Ham United F.C.).

Unfortunately, the second dropdown menu is not displaying the options that I want to be displayed at all and the problem is presented in the screenshot below

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

How do append all the clubs of the selected country as options into the second dropdown menu?

The problem is taking place is in the code presented below:

```
// clubs of 5 countries 
var englandclubs = ['Arsenal F.C.', 'Aston Villa F.C.', 'Burnley F.C.', 'Chelsea F.C.', 'Crystal Palace F.C.', 'Everton F.C.', 'Hull City A.F.C.', 'Leicester City F.C.', 'Liverpool F.C.', 'Manchester City F.C.', 'Manchester United F.C.', 'Newcastle United F.C.', 'Queens Park Rangers F.C.', 'Southampton F.C.', 'Stoke City F.C.', 'Sunderland A.F.C.', 'Swansea City A.F.C.', 'Tottenham Hotspur F.C.', 'West Bromwich Albion F.C.', 'West Ham United F.C.'];

var franceclubs = ['SC Bastia', 'FC Girondins de Bordeaux', 'Stade Malherbe Caen', 'Évian Thonon Gaillard F.C.', 'En Avant de Guingamp', 'RC Lens', 'Lille OSC', 'FC Lorient', 'Olympique Lyonnais', 'Olympique de Marseille', 'FC Metz','AS Monaco FC', 'Montpellier HSC', 'FC Nantes', 'OGC Nice', 'Paris Saint-Germain F.C.', 'Stade de Reims', 'Stade Rennais F.C.', 'AS Saint-Étienne', 'Toulouse FC'];

var germanyclubs = ['FC Augsburg', 'Bayer 04 Leverkusen', 'FC Bayern München', 'Borussia Dortmund', 'Borussia Mönchengladbach', 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 'SC Freiburg', 'Hamburger SV', 'Hannover 96', 'Hertha BSC', 'TSG 1899 Hoffenheim', '1. FC Köln', '1. FSV Mainz 05', 'SC Paderborn 07', 'FC Schalke 04', 'VfB Stuttgart', 'SV Werder Bremen', 'VfL Wolfsburg'];

var italyclubs = ['Atalanta B.C.', 'Cagliari Calcio', 'A.C. Cesena', 'A.C. Chievo Verona', 'Empoli F.C.', 'ACF Fiorentina', 'Genoa C.F.C.', 'F.C. Internazionale Milano', 'Juventus F.C.', 'S.S. Lazio', 'A.C. Milan', 'S.S.C. Napoli', 'U.S. Città di Palermo', 'Parma F.C.', 'A.S. Roma', 'U.C. Sampdoria', 'U.S. Sassuolo Calcio', 'Torino F.C.', 'Udinese Calcio', 'Hellas Verona F.C.'];

var spainclubs = ['UD Almería', 'Athletic Bilbao', 'Atlético Madrid', 'FC Barcelona', 'Celta de Vigo', 'Córdoba CF', 'Deportivo de La Coruña', 'SD Eibar', 'Elche CF', 'RCD Espanyol', 'Getafe CF', 'Granada CF', 'Levante UD', 'Málaga CF', 'Rayo Vallecano', 'Real Madrid C.F.', 'Real Sociedad', 'Sevilla FC', 'Valencia CF', 'Villarreal CF'];

// countries in UEFA
var countries = [{name: "England", clubs: englandclubs},
                 {name: "France", clubs: franceclubs},
                 {name: "Germany", clubs: germanyclubs},
                 {name: "Italy", clubs: italyclubs},
                 {name: "Spain", clubs: spainclubs}];

$(function() {

    $(".formArea").append("<form name='clubinsertion' action='#' method='post' id='clubinsertion'>" +
                          "</form>");
    $("#clubinsertion").append("<label>Country:</label>" +
                               "<br>" +
                               "<select name='countries' id='countries'>" +
                               "<option disabled selected> -- Choose a country -- </option>" +
                               "</select>" +
                               "<br>");

    // adds the name of each country to the dropdown menu
    var countrymenu = $('#countries');

    $.each(countries, function(val, obj) {
        countrymenu.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(obj.name));
    });

    $("#clubinsertion").append("<label>Club:</label>" +
                               "<br>" +
                               "<select name='clubs' id='clubs'>" +
                               "</select>" +
                               "<br>");

    // gets the selected option from the countries dropdown menu
    var selectedcountry = $('#countries option:selected').text()

    // adds each club of selected country into the clubs dropdown menu
    var clubmenu = $('#clubs');

    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        if (selectedcountry === countries[i].name) {
            $.each(countries, function(val, obj) {
                clubmenu.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(obj.clubs));
            });
        }
    }


    // submit button for the form
    $("#clubinsertion").append("<button type='submit'>Enter Club</button>");
});
```

Comment: you haven't written `onchange` event for your `select` option? and please try to add some html!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `onchange` event on `countries` drop down with event delegation like,

```
$('.formArea').on('change','#countries',function(){
      var selectedcountry = $('#countries option:selected').text();
      setClubsData(selectedcountry);
});

function setClubsData(selectedcountry){
    // adds each club of selected country into the clubs dropdown menu
    var clubmenu = $('#clubs').html('');// make it blank before append

    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        if (selectedcountry === countries[i].name) {
            // loop for countries[i].clubs not for countries
            $.each(countries[i].clubs, function(key, val) {
                // simply get the value from clup array and append it
                clubmenu.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(val));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```js
// clubs of 5 countries 
var englandclubs = ['Arsenal F.C.', 'Aston Villa F.C.', 'Burnley F.C.', 'Chelsea F.C.', 'Crystal Palace F.C.', 'Everton F.C.', 'Hull City A.F.C.', 'Leicester City F.C.', 'Liverpool F.C.', 'Manchester City F.C.', 'Manchester United F.C.', 'Newcastle United F.C.', 'Queens Park Rangers F.C.', 'Southampton F.C.', 'Stoke City F.C.', 'Sunderland A.F.C.', 'Swansea City A.F.C.', 'Tottenham Hotspur F.C.', 'West Bromwich Albion F.C.', 'West Ham United F.C.'];

var franceclubs = ['SC Bastia', 'FC Girondins de Bordeaux', 'Stade Malherbe Caen', 'Évian Thonon Gaillard F.C.', 'En Avant de Guingamp', 'RC Lens', 'Lille OSC', 'FC Lorient', 'Olympique Lyonnais', 'Olympique de Marseille', 'FC Metz', 'AS Monaco FC', 'Montpellier HSC', 'FC Nantes', 'OGC Nice', 'Paris Saint-Germain F.C.', 'Stade de Reims', 'Stade Rennais F.C.', 'AS Saint-Étienne', 'Toulouse FC'];

var germanyclubs = ['FC Augsburg', 'Bayer 04 Leverkusen', 'FC Bayern München', 'Borussia Dortmund', 'Borussia Mönchengladbach', 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 'SC Freiburg', 'Hamburger SV', 'Hannover 96', 'Hertha BSC', 'TSG 1899 Hoffenheim', '1. FC Köln', '1. FSV Mainz 05', 'SC Paderborn 07', 'FC Schalke 04', 'VfB Stuttgart', 'SV Werder Bremen', 'VfL Wolfsburg'];

var italyclubs = ['Atalanta B.C.', 'Cagliari Calcio', 'A.C. Cesena', 'A.C. Chievo Verona', 'Empoli F.C.', 'ACF Fiorentina', 'Genoa C.F.C.', 'F.C. Internazionale Milano', 'Juventus F.C.', 'S.S. Lazio', 'A.C. Milan', 'S.S.C. Napoli', 'U.S. Città di Palermo', 'Parma F.C.', 'A.S. Roma', 'U.C. Sampdoria', 'U.S. Sassuolo Calcio', 'Torino F.C.', 'Udinese Calcio', 'Hellas Verona F.C.'];

var spainclubs = ['UD Almería', 'Athletic Bilbao', 'Atlético Madrid', 'FC Barcelona', 'Celta de Vigo', 'Córdoba CF', 'Deportivo de La Coruña', 'SD Eibar', 'Elche CF', 'RCD Espanyol', 'Getafe CF', 'Granada CF', 'Levante UD', 'Málaga CF', 'Rayo Vallecano', 'Real Madrid C.F.', 'Real Sociedad', 'Sevilla FC', 'Valencia CF', 'Villarreal CF'];

// countries in UEFA
var countries = [{
  name: "England",
  clubs: englandclubs
}, {
  name: "France",
  clubs: franceclubs
}, {
  name: "Germany",
  clubs: germanyclubs
}, {
  name: "Italy",
  clubs: italyclubs
}, {
  name: "Spain",
  clubs: spainclubs
}];

$(function() {

  $('.formArea').on('change', '#countries', function() {
    var selectedcountry = $('#countries option:selected').text();
    setClubsData(selectedcountry);
  });

  function setClubsData(selectedcountry) {
    // adds each club of selected country into the clubs dropdown menu
    var clubmenu = $('#clubs').html(''); // make it blank before append

    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
      if (selectedcountry === countries[i].name) {
        // loop for countries[i].clubs not for countries
        $.each(countries[i].clubs, function(key, val) {
          // simply get the value from clup array and append it
          clubmenu.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(val));
        });
      }
    }
  }

  $(".formArea").append("<form name='clubinsertion' action='#' method='post' id='clubinsertion'>" +
    "</form>");
  $("#clubinsertion").append("<label>Country:</label>" +
    "<br>" +
    "<select name='countries' id='countries'>" +
    "<option disabled selected> -- Choose a country -- </option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "<br>");

  // adds the name of each country to the dropdown menu
  var countrymenu = $('#countries');

  $.each(countries, function(val, obj) {
    countrymenu.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(obj.name));
  });

  $("#clubinsertion").append("<label>Club:</label>" +
    "<br>" +
    "<select name='clubs' id='clubs'>" +
    "</select>" +
    "<br>");

  // gets the selected option from the countries dropdown menu
  var selectedcountry = $('#countries option:selected').text();
  setClubsData(selectedcountry);
  // adds each club of selected country into the clubs dropdown menu
  /*var clubmenu = $('#clubs');

  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    if (selectedcountry === countries[i].name) {
      $.each(countries, function(val, obj) {
        clubmenu.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(obj.clubs));
      });
    }
  }*/


  // submit button for the form
  $("#clubinsertion").append("<button type='submit'>Enter Club</button>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formArea">
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Dependent drop-down plug in.

http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown/demo

Or cascading dropdown plugin

http://www.dnasir.com/github/jquery-cascading-dropdown/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by a simplest way :

1 - add dropdown for countries with options to choose (option value is name of country).

2 - try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#country_dropdown").on('change',function(){
         var country_name = $(this).val();
         for(var k in countries){
             if(contries[k].name==country_name){
                //it's country which selected by user
                var club_dropdown=$('<div/>',{
                    id:'club_dropdown'
                });
                for(var s in countries[k].clubs){
                    club_dropdown.append('<option value="'+countries[k].clubs[s]+'">'+countries[k].clubs[s]+'"</option>"');
                }
                club_dropdown.appendTo($(".formArea"));
             }
         }
    });
});

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is how your `change` function looks like and before that I would like to show you the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/okLapc35/)**

```
$('#countries').on('change',function(){
    var country=$(this).find(":selected").text();
    $('#clubs').find('option').remove();
    switch(country)
    {
        case 'England':
            $.each(englandclubs, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#clubs')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value)); 
            });
            break;
        case 'France':
            $.each(franceclubs, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#clubs')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value));  
            });
        case 'Germany':
            $.each(germanyclubs, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#clubs')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value)); 
            });
            break;
        case 'Italy':
            $.each(italyclubs, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#clubs')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value)); 
            });
            break;
        case 'Spain':
            $.each(spainclubs, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#clubs')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .text(value)); 
            });
            break;
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I shortened your solution so that it uses a for loop and an if statement instead of the switch statement because I plan on using 54 countries instead of 5 and a switch statement would take up lots of lines of code. Sorry if I didn't add HTML code in the solution because I was using Jade as a markup language for HTML as this is a web application written using Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
$('#countries').on('change', function (e) {
    var clubmenu = $('#clubs');
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);

    var clubsArray = countries[this.value].clubs;
    $.each(clubsArray, function(ind, val) {
        clubmenu.append($('<option></option>').val(ind).html(val));
    });
});
```